# How to get the IDatabaseInstance of Amazon Aurora

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

```js
    const dbCluster = new rds.DatabaseCluster(this, 'Database', {
      parameterGroup,
      engine: engine,
      credentials: rdsCredentials,
      cloudwatchLogsExports:['slowquery','general','error','audit'],
      backup: backupProps,
      instances:instances,
      storageEncrypted:true,
      removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
      clusterIdentifier: dbInfos['cluster'], //clusterIdentifier,
      defaultDatabaseName :dbInfos['database'], //defaultDatabaseName,
      instanceProps: {
        instanceType: instanceType,
        vpcSubnets:props.vpc.selectSubnets({ subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED }),
        vpc:props!.vpc,
        securityGroups:[dbSecurityGroup],
      },
      subnetGroup:subnetGroup
    });

    new rds.DatabaseInstanceReadReplica(this, 'ReadReplica', {
      sourceDatabaseInstance: dbCluster, // error

      instanceType: ec2.InstanceType.of(ec2.InstanceClass.BURSTABLE2, ec2.InstanceSize.SMALL),
      vpc,
    });
```

There comes the error at `sourceDatabaseInstance: dbCluster`

```
    Type 'DatabaseCluster' is missing the following properties from type 'IDatabaseInstance': instanceIdentifier, instanceArn, dbInstanceEndpointAddress, dbInstanceEndpointPort, and 6 more.ts(2740)
    instance.d.ts(676, 14): The expected type comes from property 'sourceDatabaseInstance' which is declared here on type 'DatabaseInstanceReadReplicaProps'
```

Now I am trying to add read replicas to Amazon Aurora:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_rds.DatabaseInstanceReadReplica.html

`DatabaseInstanceReadReplica` accepts the `sourceDatabaseInstance` as `IDatabaseInstance`

However `Aurora` has `cluster` but not `instance`.

So what should I set here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add Aurora replicas with the [instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_rds.DatabaseCluster.html#instances) prop:

```js
instances: 3; // = 1 writer + 2 replicas
```

As the Aurora Replicas [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Replication.html#Aurora.Replication.Replicas) say:

> When you create a second, third, and so on DB instance in an Aurora provisioned DB cluster, Aurora automatically sets up replication from the writer DB instance to all the other DB instances. These other DB instances are read-only and are known as Aurora Replicas. We also refer to them as reader instances when discussing the ways that you can combine writer and reader DB instances within a cluster.

Comment: Wow, it's quite nice and easy. This solves my problem! thank you very much.